# Generic way of processing multiple queues with streadway library

Tags: go, rabbitmq, amqp, goroutine

I am looking at processing thousand of messages coming from multiple RabbitMQ queues (between 5 and 10) and push the processed messages by batch into ELK.

What would be the best generic way to process `n` queues with the streadway/amqp library?

What exactly should be included in each goroutine, in term of `amqp.Connection`, `amqp.Channel` and `amqp.Consume`r.

I mainly see 3 designs:

*A) 1 Connection - 1 Channel - n Consumers*

*B) 1 Connection - n Channels - 1 Consumer*

*C) n Connection - 1 Channel - 1 Consummer*

A) does not work for me:

```
Failed to register a consumer: Exception (504) Reason: "channel/connection is not open"
```

Each of those goroutine will then buffer `x` messages and make a BatchRequest to ELK independently from the others.

For now, starting 1 connection per queue (C) seems to work even if I have to deal with high memory consumption from the server. Is it really the most effective design or should I keep 1 connection per worker handling all 5 to 10 channels?

Here is (C) with one connection per queue.

```
func main() {
    queues := []string{"q1", "q2", "q3", "q4"}

    forever := make(chan bool)
    for _, queue := range queues {
        go processQueue(queue)
    }
    <-forever
}

func processQueue(name string) {
    conn, _ := amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
    defer conn.Close()

    ch, _ := conn.Channel()
    defer ch.Close()

    msgs, _ := ch.Consume(name, "test-dev", false, false, false, false, nil)
    go func() {
        for d := range msgs {
            log.Printf("[%s] %s", name, d.RoutingKey)
            d.Ack(true)
        }
    }()
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: How many queues are you dealing with?

Comment: @oocilec Here is a quick example of my proof of concept so far

Comment: @LukeBakken I am dealing with 5 queues, no more than 10 on the long run.

Comment: That is hardly any queues. Just use a connection per queue.

Comment: That works well!